# OpenPyxl Adding Data from different rows into a single series? (Python)

Tags: python, openpyxl, graphing

I am building a parser and I want to graph data from multiple rows that all refer to the same series.

```
row1: Happiness Data - 34 - 55534- 345 - 6456
row2: Sadness Data - 1 - 3 - 55 - 685
.
.
.
row345: Happiness Data - 34 - 55534- 345 - 6456
row346: Sadness Data - 1 - 3 - 55 - 685
```

Here I only have two series, sadness data and happiness data. I want to get each row containing each respective data set and graph it into their respective series.

Each script run, the number of rows may vary, but I have built a function to find all the rows containing happiness data and all the rows containing the hypothetical sadness data.

Is this possible?

Clear Problem Explanation:
Continuously append data from different rows into the same series name without having it duplicate multiple series under the same name.

Comment: It looks like you might want to run your data through Pandas to be able to get a pivot of it and then add that to your spreadsheet. That will automatically group data for the relevant series.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics for a data series are pretty minimal so technically it should be possible to have a non-contiguous series of cell addresses of the form `Sheet1!A1;Sheet1!A3` but I don't think this is the way to go. Much better to sort your data into contiguous blocks (using something like Pandas).

Comment: I've tried numerous things  and still can't get non-contiguous cells to house under the same data series. Is there a possible example you can lay out for this that doesn't involve pandas?